# Run js method before posting Html.BeginForm

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm using `Html.BeginForm` in Razor View, this is a login form triggered by a button. Also, to this button, I have attached `onclick` event to get token with ajax from external rest api. I want to queue this (as I figured, button triggers 2 events asynchronous).

**Is there any way, to make this api call before submiting form from html?**

```
<section id="loginForm" class="form-signin">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { role = "form" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <label>
            <div class="checkbox">
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe)
            </div>
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Sign in" id="loginBtn"class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block btn-signin" />
    }
</section>
```

This is simple MVC5 snippet.

Comment: Can you move form post from HTML to use ajax instead?

Comment: Have you tried `Ajax.BeginForm` in place of `Html.BeginForm`? And where the JS method to run before submit takes place?

Comment: You can try with JQuery submit and then call your function in submit method.

Comment: I was thinking about what you suggest guys, but after more research I decided to get token in controller and save it to cookie.

Answer (score 0):

can not run js event befor submit form bay onbegin parametr.

but you can simulate this work, change input type from **submit to button** and then add **onclick** attribut.

```
<section id="loginForm" class="form-signin">
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl, id = "LoginForm" }, FormMethod.Post, new { role = "form" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <label>
        <div class="checkbox">
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe)
        </div>
    </label>
    <input type="button" onclick="clickloginformbtn();" value="Sign in" id="loginBtn"class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block btn-signin" />
}
```

**then in .js file write this function:**

```
function clickloginformbtn(){
  //your code here
  $("#LoginForm").submit();
}
```